# How do I get checkbox value in a sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes called cBox1, cBox2 etc in a sheet called 'Images'.

[image]

I have three sheets: Data Table, Images, Data (respectively). `Images` contains two images with various checkboxes, a textbox and a button. When I click the button, the code gets value from the textbox and checkboxes and insert values into a table in the `Data` sheet.

I am trying to get whether a checkbox is checked or not with the below code:

```
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Shapes("cBox1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 0 Then
    totalOfWeldsInOrder = totalOfWeldsInOrder + 1
    s1 = 0
    notInOrder = True
End If
```

However, the value never changes.

How can I get the checked value of the checkboxes?

I have also tried the below, with no success:

```
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Shapes("cBox1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = -4146 Then
    totalOfWeldsInOrder = totalOfWeldsInOrder + 1
    s1 = 0
    notInOrder = True
End If
```

And Also

```
If Sheet2.Shapes("cBox1").ControlFormat.Value = xlOff Then
   ......
End If
```

EDIT:

```
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).cBox1.Value = 0 Then
    totalOfWeldsInOrder = totalOfWeldsInOrder + 1
    s1 = 0
    notInOrder = True
End If
```

returns:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `msgbox (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Shapes("cBox1").OLEFormat.Object.Value)` to verify it's definitely changing, worksheets "Images" is definitely worksheets(2)? I am trying to reproduce an error but it's working successfully for me :/

Comment: What I mean is, I am using `MsgBox (ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1").OLEFormat.Object.Value)` and depending on whether it's checked or not, I get either a 1 or a -4146. An IF condition works fine for this so I assume your problem is finding the checkbox, on a different worksheet or called something else maybe.

Comment: Try changing `Worksheets(2)` to `Worksheets("Images")`

Comment: @jamheadart changing to Worksheets("Images") produces an error

Comment: Is it a "Subscript out of range" or `Run Time Error 9` ? I supsect you're not actually checking the right sheet here.

Comment: @jamheadart The error on `msgbox (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Shapes("cBox1").OLEFormat.Object‌​.Value)` is `Object doesn't support this property or method (Run-time error 428)`

Comment: @jamheadart when I try `MsgBox (ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1").OLEFormat.Object.Value)` I get the error: `The item with the specified name wasn't found (Run-time error: -2147024809)`

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple solution to your problem:

**Use an Active-X Checkbox**. Under Developmenttools tab in the menu bar there is: "Insert" it lets you insert two kinds of checkboxes, two kinds of every control strucutre infact. One is an active-x component which is more recent and the other ones are just for backwards compatibility reasons. So never use anything else then Active-X components. Then the code can be used as followed:

```
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Checkbox1.Value = False Then
    totalOfWeldsInOrder = totalOfWeldsInOrder + 1
    s1 = 0
    notInOrder = True
End If
```

The Checkbox name "CheckBox1" can be changed by showing and editing it's properties so it might also be called "okbox" this name will then replace CheckBox1 in your code.

Comment: There's a screen-extension size issue with using ActiveX components on worksheets however, be aware if you're going to be sending these code books out to people with laptops who dock and extend their screens a lot.

Comment: @jamheadart nice to know! Didn't know that. Is there a was this?

Comment: @LucasRaphaelPianegonda I have tried changing one of them but I receive an error message. See updated question at the bottomn